# How to display numbers which are like 11111 or similar in MS sql

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, database

I am trying to display numbers from ID column which should have the same number.

Like 11111 or 2222 or 33333

`select * from table where id like '1111'` - this will give me 1 value, but there are many values like 1111111111 or 111111 which I am not sure of, as there are more than 100k records.

Comment: what about numbers like `11112345`, they should be considered as well or it needs to be all `1's` in the id ?

Comment: no the value should be same as the first number.. like 111111 or 222222 or 3333333 or 44444 etc..

Answer (score 3):

Using regular expressions

```
SELECT * from table where id REGEXP '^(1+|2+|3+|4+|5+|6+|7+|8+|9+)$';
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with regular expressions, such as this:

```
where id regex '^((1+)|(2+)|(3+)|(4+)|(5+)|(6+)|(7+)|(8+)|(9+)|(0+))$'
```

Upon [testing](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/7677), this needs an extra set of parentheses (just added).

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers must match the first one, you can capture the first digit and then use a back-reference to it:

```
^([0-9])\1+$
```

This will work if you have [LIB_MYSQLUDF_PREG](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg) installed that imports the PCRE library (as per [Regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/mysql.html)). And the syntax will be `PREG_RLIKE('/^([0-9])\\1+$/i', col)`.

Comment: Are you sure backreferences are supported?

Comment: It depends if LIB_MYSQLUDF_PREG is installed. I will update with a disclaimer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the % wildcard

If you want to include numbers like 2341111, 1111342 or 23111154 etc

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id LIKE '%1111%'
```

If you want only numbers with the same numeric value 1111 or 1111111 or 11111111 etc

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE id LIKE '1%11%1'
```

Comment: @Sandeep Very true, depends on his requirements, i will edit for multiple scenarios

Comment: The second query won't work.  It will include values like 121121, 122221122221, etc.